# Bash: perform math on negative integers with leading zeros

Tags: bash

Given a math operation in bash like

`a=$(( ${b} + 1 ))`

how do I handle cases where `b` can be either positive or negative with leading zeros?  If I try

`a=$(( 10#${b} + 1 ))`

for `b=009`, this is successful.  But if I try the same for `b=-001`, this returns an error:

`10#: invalid integer constant (error token is "10#")`

So is there a way to handle these sorts of cases in a single line?  Or is there a way to check if `b` is less than 0?  For the latter option, I have tried

`[[ $b < 0 ]] && a=$(( ${b} + 1 )) || a=$(( 10#${b} + 1 ))`

but this runs into a similar error in the conditional if `b` is greater than or equal to `008`.

PS: the reason I need the `10#` prefix is that numbers starting with leading zeros are interpreted as octal otherwise.

Comment: How about removing the leading zeroes first?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the `10#` in front since that's the default base. From the title of your question, is your actual use case with octal numbers and is `$(( 8#${b} ))` what you're trying to make work with positives and negatives?

Comment: For what it's worth, `$(( -8#123 ))` works, so it looks like the negative sign needs to be placed before the base qualifier.

Comment: @Barmar that may work.  I need the other digits for a string later on, but I could create a temporary variable for the calculation then add the zeros back in.

Comment: @joanis I have tried to clarify the title.  The base that I’m working with is 10, not 8, and I want to preserve it as such.  Bash assumes leading zeros to indicate octal, so that’s why `10#` is needed.

Comment: OK, that all makes more sense now.

Comment: [BashPitfalls/059](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#i.3D.24.28.28_10.23.24i_.29.29) seems to have a (very ugly) solution if you want a quick fix.

Comment: If you are running Bash 5.2 or later then you could enable extended globbing with `shopt -s extglob` and then use `a=$(( ${b/#*(-)/&10#} + 1 ))`

Comment: `$(( ${b} + 1 ))` works for me with `b` set to `-001` (using bash 5.2), and correctly evaluates to 0. Please post a screnshot which demonstrates in which way your example does not work.

Comment: @user1934428 `b=-009; echo $(( ${b} + 1 ))` outputs `bash: -009: value too great for base (error token is "009")`. -001 means the same thing in bases 8 and 10, the errors only occurs where they differ.

Comment: Ah, with `-009` and `009` I see the same. You can't use the digit 9 in an octal number, but this is not related to negative or positive. The same error occurs in `b=009; echo $(( $b + 1 ))`. The problem is when loading the value into the variable. Why do you have a zero at the beginning in the first place? If the mathematical meaning of the number is just `9` or `-9`, store this into the variable. If you really **want** to work with octal numbers, find out where the `9` comes from.

Comment: What I would do is to write a function which "sanitizes" such an integer string, by preserving the starting sign (if any), and then delete all leading zeroes. Using the bash regexp operator, this is easy to do. Then apply this function to your values, as soon as they enter your script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax to specify the base expects the negative sign, if any, before the base specifier.

```
$ echo $(( -10#0123 + 1 ))
-122
```

So something like this could work:

```
b=-009
b_with_base="10#$b"
echo $(( ${b_with_base/10#-/-10#} + 1 ))
```

outputs `-8` with `b=-009` and `10` with `b=009`.

Comment: Hum, this is basically the same idea @tjm3772 linked to in their last comment, although that one puts it all together in a one liner.

Comment: It's the same concept but yours is much more readable in my opinion, so I do prefer this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could extract the minus, and then everything without the minus, and put `10#` in between

```
$ f() { b=$1; echo $(( ${b%%[^-+]*}10#${b##[-+]} + 1 )); }
$ f -009
-8
$ f 009
10
$ f +009
10
```